# Deploying Crowdsale.sol - Error

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, crowdsale, error

In order to enable purchases of MyToken, **where do I include the RATE (token/ETH)** such as the below code from [Openzeppelin docs on crowdsales](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/crowdsales#crowdsale-rate) into my deploy_contract.js or MyToken.sol? And how to insert it?

```
new Crowdsale(
    1,             // rate in TKNbits
    WALLET,     // address where Ether is sent
    TOKEN  // the token contract address
);
```

Here are the Simpletoken, Crowdsale, and deployment contracts from [Openzeppelin](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/simple-erc20-crowdsale/4863):

```
/ contracts/SimpleToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract SimpleToken is Context, ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply
    ) public ERC20Detailed(name, symbol, 18) {
        _mint(_msgSender(), initialSupply);
    }
}

// contracts/SimpleCrowdsale.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.5.5;
    
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";

contract SimpleCrowdsale is Crowdsale {
    constructor(
        uint256 rate,
        address payable wallet,
        IERC20 token
    ) public Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token) {}
}

// migrations/2_deploy.js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
const SimpleToken = artifacts.require("SimpleToken");
const SimpleCrowdsale = artifacts.require("SimpleCrowdsale");

module.exports = async function (deployer, network, accounts) {
  await deployer.deploy(SimpleToken, 'Simple Token', 'SIM', '10000000000000000000000');
  const token = await SimpleToken.deployed();
  
  await deployer.deploy(SimpleCrowdsale, 1, accounts[0], token.address);
  const crowdsale = await SimpleCrowdsale.deployed();

  token.transfer(crowdsale.address, await token.totalSupply())
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include it in the *deploy_contract.js*, as you are already doing it here:

```
await deployer.deploy(SimpleCrowdsale, 1, accounts[0], token.address);
```

the argument **1** is the RATE you are providing.

Comment: wow. thank you i totally missed that!

Comment: Glad it helped, please mark the answer as the correct one if it resolved your issue.